# How to identify which object in array of objects?

Tags: swift

I am trying to return which object that meet the following condition:

For example:

1. 3 array of Custom data type object: **`let array = [incomplete, unlisted, listed]`**
2. iterate thru the array, find and return the object which hold the attribute data needed: **`for i in 0...array.count - 1 {if array[i].dataId == dataId {)}`**

I want to return which object of the 3 in the **`array`** that has the attribute data: **`incomplete, unlisted`** or **`listed`**?

Comment: i didn't get what you want to achieve , could you better explain your question

Comment: I think in your question you meant `array` instead of `listing`. So people are confused and are not understanding your question.

Comment: incomplete, unlisted, listed are they specific objects ???

Comment: @Mundi updated to `array`

Answer (score -2):

The swifty thing to do here is to use `filter`.

```
let filteredObject = array.filter { $0.dataId == filterId }
```

The `$0` is the object in the array.